# Jest with Angular8 and Node 13 Segmentation fault

Tags: node.js, angular, jestjs

I've been following [Angular CLI: “ng test” with Jest in 3 minutes (v2)](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-cli-ng-test-with-jest-in-3-minutes-v2-1060ddd7908d) tutorial to set up jest tests with Angular 8.

My test fails on node 13 with Segmentation fault, but passes on node 12

The test is very simple:

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {HttpService} from './http.service';

describe('HttpService', () => {
  let service: HttpService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
      ],
      providers: [
      ]
    });

    service = TestBed.get(HttpService);
  });

  it('should be created1', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be created2', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be created3', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be created4', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be created5', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be created6', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be created7', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Class under tests:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {
}
```

I also noticed that the test passes if there are 5 or less test cases, and always fails on the 6th test.

**EDIT**

I checked that:

- node 13.1 works fine, the problem appears only on 13.2.
- same tests work perfectly fine on karma/jasmine

Here is [Github Workflow showing the issue](https://github.com/lesiak/node13-angular-jest/commit/beec00272208404ce9c490d6d4dab40fbb9e6125/checks?check_suite_id=334253246), with all 3 node versions in the test matrix.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Added a bug report for jest: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9244